# Load a yaml file and Iterate over a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, yaml, pytest, pyyaml

I have a yaml file with the below content:

```
testcases:
 - testcase_1:
    username:
    password:
 - testcase_2:
    username:
    password:
```

How do I iterate through the over content. I want first to run testcases with the variables present inside testcases_1 and then later run testcases with variables in testcase_2. ? How do I do this ?///

Comment: you can install the yaml module to load the file.  `pip install pyyaml`   https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/

Comment: It looks like you are actually asking for *several* things – loading a YAML, iterating over a list, and running test cases. Which of these are you struggling with?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi hey thanks for replying. So the main thing which I am focusing on is to iterate over the list and further run testcases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `yaml.safe_load` function to load the content and then you can iterate over it:

```
import yaml

content = None

with open("D:/data.yml") as f:
    try:
        content = yaml.safe_load(f)
    except yaml.YAMLError as e:
        print(e)

print(content)

for item in content['testcases']:
    print(item)
```

Above code will output:

```
{'testcases': [{'testcase_1': {'username': None, 'password': None}}, {'testcase_2': {'username': None, 'password': None}}]}
{'testcase_1': {'username': None, 'password': None}}
{'testcase_2': {'username': None, 'password': None}}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for replying. I tried what you suggested. But none of the print statement is working. How can I change it ?

Comment: Hi Sunita! I have copy-pasted the code in my IDE and the `prints` are working fine. You can go without them. I'm updating now the response to show how `content` looks. It contains the data from the file formatted as a `dict`. From than on, you can parse and extract any data you need from it

Comment: Hey Dan.. Thanks for all your help. I have slightly changed the content for the yaml file. Could you please have a look ?N yes I will surely look at your changes.

Comment: I have updated the output based on your latest changes

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan !!! It worked.